# Android: onResume() not called after pressing home button

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, oncreate, onresume

I have an activity that makes a call to a remote server when it's started.
The thing is, that when the app is on the background, and the server creates new content, when restoring my app, this new content is not seen unless the app is killed and started again.

I put the code that gets all this info from the server in the 'onResume()' method, which works when the app is killed and started again, but not if it's only sent to the background pressing the home button.

Why doesn't the 'onResume()' method get call? How can I do to have it called?

Thanks a lot in advance!

This is the code I have:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Server server = new Server(this);
        server.GetHighlights(10, 0, null);
        server.GetNews(10, 0, null);
        server.GetBrands(12, 0, null);
        Log.i("XS2", "Resume");
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        Log.i("XS2", "Create");
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_media_player);
        mPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        if (mPreview != null) {
            mHolder = mPreview.getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
        }

//      Server server = new Server(this);
//      server.GetHighlights(10, 0, null);
//      server.GetNews(10, 0, null);
//      server.GetBrands(12, 0, null);

        // google analytics set up
        AnalyticsHelper.initializeTrackerInstance(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

Comment: onResume is always called if app has been in background and is brought to the front again. Problem must lie elsewhere... Maybe show some code....

Comment: onResume is being called. Can you show us your code snippet (for example updating the ui after retrieving data)\

Comment: I also put 'Log' when calling onResume() and onCreate() and when restoring my app, I can't see neither

Comment: @noloman put the Log at the beginning of the onResume and check again please

Comment: @SherifelKhatib same thing happening, it doesn't even enter in debug mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, the problem was mine: my activity redirected to a fragment (it was a splash acitivity and when it finished, it would start the fragment). And it's in this fragment where I should have put the 'onResume()'.

Thanks everybody for the help!